# Setting up a project that includes Pods and will be released on CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm in this situation... I'm starting a new SDK that I want to release through CocoaPods, the SDK itself needs some Pods (`AFNetworking`)
I wonder which is the best way to setup the project, given that I need to try the SDK in an example project while writing it.

My first attempt started with the `pod lib create` command. I followed all the instruction and I ended up with a complete workspace, wonderful! now how can I include `AFNetworking`? I have to add it as dependency in the `mySDK.podspec` file using: `s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'` so that users of my SDK can also have it included into the library, great. But how can I have it included in my current project to use it during development?

I see that under the "Example" folder created by cocoapods I have a `Podfile` but it contains only the example and test target... I've tried to include the SDK target here but it doesn't seem to work that way.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'MYSDK_Example', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'MYSDK', :path => '../'
end

target 'MYSDK_Tests', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'MYSDK', :path => '../'

  pod 'Specta'
  pod 'Expecta'
end
```

I've tried to include the next configuration and launch again pod install...

```
target 'MYSDK', :exclusive => true do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
end
```

I get a generic terrible error and anyway it doesn't sound really good as solution.

This is the structure created by the lib create command, **where I'm supposed to add a new Podfile to include the library that I need to develop the library?**

```
 MyLib
  ├── _Pods.xcproject
  ├── Example
  │   ├── MyLib
  │   ├── MyLib.xcodeproj
  │   ├── MyLib.xcworkspace
  │   ├── Podfile    <----- the Podfile previously described
  │   ├── Podfile.lock
  │   ├── Pods
  │   └── Tests
  ├── MyLib.podspec
  ├── Pod
  │   ├── Assets
  │   └── Classes
  │     └── TheFilesForMyLib.[swift/m] <---- My Lib code
```

Answer (score 2):

How I did it was to have a `Podfile` for my library as well. In this `Podfile` I have all the dependency.

Here my libraries `Podfile`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'

workspace 'SAFoundation.xcworkspace'

xcodeproj 'SAFoundation.xcodeproj'

pod 'AFNetworking'
```

Comment: Where do you add this podfile exactly? I've the structure created by the pod lib create command.

Comment: This is just the podfile for the project library that you want to submit to the Cocoapods respository.

Comment: The project structure created by the `pod lib create` command already contains a Podfile. I update my answer to help you guys better understand where is my problem.